# Stylegan3: How to save specific tick state in a file and resume training from that file?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network, stylegan

I'm using Google Colab to train Stylegan3 on my data. I can resume from .pkl file.

But I want to save a specific tick state in a file and then resume training from that file. How can I do it? I've checked PyTorch model saving and resuming but no clue about Stylegan3 tick saving and resuming.

Stylegan3 official repo: https://github.com/NVlabs/stylegan3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

"When you run train.py, one of the options you have is `--snap`, which is how often (in ticks) you will save snapshots of your trained model, so you can set `--snap=100`.

To resume from this tick, they will be saved as network-snapshot-000100.pkl, for example, so again when you run train.py, you use `--resume=/path/to/network-snapshot-000100.pkl`, where you input the actual path to that .pkl file."

from https://github.com/NVlabs/stylegan3/issues/67